# pytest fails on github action with no output, error code 1

Tags: python, pytest, github-actions

I'm running pytest on a self-hosted windows runner (windows server 2019), but it fails with no output, just says `exit code 1`. No output also despite using debug mode on the runner.

I get python via `actions/setup-python@v4`. Dependencies are installed with `python -m pip install -e '.[dev]'`, including `pytest`.

Logs of action run:

```
Run pytest --version
  pytest --version
  shell: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
  env:
    ACTIONS_RUNNER_DEBUG: true
  
    pythonLocation: C:\Users\User1\GHA_abs\_work\_tool\Python\3.9.13\x64
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: C:\Users\User1\GHA_abs\_work\_tool\Python\3.9.13\x64/lib/pkgconfig
    Python_ROOT_DIR: C:\Users\User1\GHA_abs\_work\_tool\Python\3.9.13\x64
    Python2_ROOT_DIR: C:\Users\User1\GHA_abs\_work\_tool\Python\3.9.13\x64
    Python3_ROOT_DIR: C:\Users\User1\GHA_abs\_work\_tool\Python\3.9.13\x64
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the root cause, but `pytest` can be run with `python -m pytest`. This way it behaves fully normal.